# Segue away from PageViewControllers?

Tags: storyboard, segue, uipageviewcontroller

I'm very new to using xcode and I've encountered a problem. Tried looking through UIPageView, but I couldn't find that many resources on UIPageView overall.

I have a UIPageView (that is split into three different h/m files like in the default PageViewApplications) that shows many jpg files, and I would like to find a way to segue away from that to go to a different ViewController once it reaches the end. I've written a code in ModelController as such:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:(DataViewController *)viewController];
    if (index == NSNotFound){
    return nil;
    }

    index++;

    if (index == [myJpgArray count]){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self];
    }

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index storyboard:viewController.storyboard];

}
```

But from this code,

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self];
```

part gets an error saying, "No visible @interface for 'ModelController' declares the selector 'performSegueWithIdentifier:sender.'"

I hope this is clear enough for a question, but I hope someone can enlighten me with an answer!

Answer (score 0):

performSegueWithIdentifier is a method of the UIViewController class. Unless your ModelController is a sub class of UIViewController the method will not be available. Without understanding your application fully it's not possible to be certain but I think you need to execute this logic in your view controller (which should be a subclass of UIPageViewController).

Hope this helps

Comment: after using your tips, i think i can almost figure it out. Thanks for the advice! :)